# How to solve $M=\frac{t}{\ln(1+t)} - \frac{t^3}{(1+t) (\ln(1+t))^2 }$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve $M=\frac{t}{\ln(1+t)} - \frac{t^3}{(1+t) (\ln(1+t))^2 }$ where $M$ is a constant and $t = \frac{a}{x}$, $a$ is a constant and $x$ is the variable. Here $ 0 < x \leq X_{max}$. I wonder if there is a closed-form solution for the formula above.

Comment: @mr_e_man That is the former.

Comment: @mr_e_man Here is this. :)

Comment: Just looking at it, I don't expect a closed-form solution, except possibly something with Lambert's $W$ function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  mr_e_man commented, it would be surprising that a closed form exist (even using special functions).

If $M$ is a large negative number, using Taylor,
$$\frac{t}{\ln(1+t)} - \frac{t^3}{(1+t) (\ln(1+t))^2 }\approx -\frac{t^2}{\log^2(t)}$$ and then an *approximate* solution is given by
$$t=-\sqrt{-M}\,\, W_{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-M}}{M}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). The Wikipedia page provides series for a shortcut evaluation of $W(x)$ when $x$ is small or large.

This is not too bad as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
M & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 -100 & 35.7715 &  39.3988 \\
 -200 & 57.2358 & 60.9711 \\
 -300 & 74.7152 &  78.5249 \\
 -400 & 89.9951 &  93.8614 \\
 -500 & 103.811 &  107.723 \\
 -600 & 116.556 &  120.506 \\
 -700 & 128.470 &  132.453 \\
 -800 & 139.713 &  143.725 \\
 -900 & 150.399 &  154.437 \\
 -1000 & 160.612 & 164.674
\end{array}
\right)$$ making Newton method converging in very few iterations.

If $M$ is a  positive number, using Taylor again,
$$\frac{t}{\ln(1+t)} - \frac{t^3}{(1+t) (\ln(1+t))^2 }=1-\frac{t}{2}-\frac{t^2}{12}+O\left(t^3\right)$$ which could be a way to get an *estimate* for $0 \leq M \leq 1.5$.

In any manner, a numerical method (such as Newton) would be required to polish the root.